# how can i use axis2 as runtime in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to generate web service from pojo using axis2.  But in eclipse, i am not able to geneate a service as the ok button disabled.  How do i enable it?

[image: eclipse]

When I try to enable Axis2 Web Services facets, I am getting this error "Axis2 Web services core1.1 requires Dynamic Web Module with version matching expression "2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5"."  what does it mean?

Is there any other way to convert pojo to web service for complex data types?

Answer (score 10):

This means that when you create a new web project, in the first step of the wizard you have a combobox allowing you to select the Dynamic web module version. You should select one of the versions it suggests you to.